# Find first instance of text in a string from values in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a string with a date and start/stop times.  I've managed to split the dates out of the string, but am unsure how to pull the start/stop times.

My string looks like `Jun/22/177:57am5:13pm9:16` where `Jun/22/17` is the date, `7:57am` is the start time, `5:13pm` is the stop time, and `9:16` is the duration in hours and minutes.

I have managed to pull out the date values into separate variables (to be used later)

```py
x = "Jun/22/177:57am5:13pm9:16"

fulldate_str = x[x.find(" ")+1:x.find("/17")+3]
fulldate = datetime.strptime(fulldate_str, "%b/%d/%y")

date_day = fulldate.day
date_month = fulldate.month
date_year = fulldate.year
```

However can I get the start time and the end time?  I can pull the rest of the string using

```py
inout = x[x.find("/17")+3:]
```

which returns

```py
7:57am5:13pm9:16
```

but I am unsure how to stop after the `am` and again at the `pm`, and then for the duration as well.  The start time won't always be `am`, and the stop won't always be `pm`, so I'm thinking I need to check against a list `['am', 'pm']` but

1. I don't know how, and
2. I think there should be a better way I could do this.

This works, but only if `am` is first and `pm` is second:

```py
time_in = x[x.find("/17")+3:x.find("am",x.find("/17")+3)+2]
time_out = x[x.find("am",x.find("/17")+3)+2:x.find("pm")+2]
duration = x[x.find("pm")+2:]
```

Of course I don't *need* the duration, as it could be calculated later easily enough.

Comment: out of curiosity do you have any control over the input string is created?

Comment: @Hopeless None at all, sorry.  It is output from a machine.  We get either a nicely formatted html page (not useful) or a text file.  I am trying to read the text file line by line and put the values into a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to extract the date, start, and stop times using a regular expression, build the full start date-time and stop date-time from the components, and then parse them into `datetime` objects using `strptime`. Once they're stored as objects they can simply be subtracted to provide the duration

Here's what that looks like. I've built the `start` and `stop` strings with a space before the time to make them a little more readable; the parser doesn't need them

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

dts = "Jun/22/177:57am5:13pm9:16"

match = re.match(r'([a-z]{3}/\d\d/\d\d)(\d\d?:\d\d[ap]m)(\d\d?:\d\d[ap]m)', dts, flags=re.I)

if match :

    start = '{} {}'.format(match.group(1), match.group(2))
    stop  = '{} {}'.format(match.group(1), match.group(3))

    start = datetime.strptime(start, '%b/%d/%y %I:%M%p')
    stop  = datetime.strptime(stop,  '%b/%d/%y %I:%M%p')

    print(start)
    print(stop)
```

#### output

```
2017-06-22 07:57:00
2017-06-22 17:13:00
```

#### Regex pattern

- `[a-z]` matches any letter from `a` to `z`, and `[a-z]{3}` matches three of them
- Slashes and colons match themselves, as does `m`
- `\d` matches a decimal digit
- `?` makes the preceding item optional, so `\d\d?` matches a one- or two-digit number
- `[ap]` matches either `a` or `p`
- Parentheses "capture" the string they match, and are available through `match.group(n)` and `match.groups()`
- `match` will be `None` if the pattern fails to match

Comment: I do like this one, particularly returning in datetime (something I hadn't considered, but I can see the benefit).  I'll have a play and see if I can get it to work through my data.

Comment: @Midavolo: I added the `strptime` because, as you say, it's generally quite useful, and because you parsed the date the same way in your own code. If you don't need it then the date and the two times are in `match.groups()`

Comment: Yes I had used it for the date, but had never considered the benefit of combining the time with it also.  There is potential (I'm still looking through the inputs) of stop times being the next day (or even later I guess) so this would be needed.  Of course I don't know yet how the times would be represented in the input data if this were the case.

Comment: @Midavolo: That's odd. It's a very strange data format altogether! You really should get your head around regex patterns as they can be invaluable. They're basically little more than a fancy glob pattern, but the `re` module has a clumsy API. I mostly use Perl, where regexes are built into the language.

Comment: I suspect I would see something like `Jun/22/177:57amJun/23/175:13am21:16` or the like if it spans other days, but I'm yet to see one in the data.  If that happens I guess I'll be back here with another question

Comment: @Midavolo: I've added a short cheat sheet for the stuff I've used in the regex pattern

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that should work with any ordering of `am/pm` and also should handle times that are 3 or 4 digits in length (eg. 5:00pm vs 12:00am):

```
x = "Jun/2/175:00pm12:00am9:16"

fulldate_str = x[x.find(" ")+1:x.find("/17")+3]
fulltime_spt = x[len(fulldate_str):].split("m")
for t in range(0,2):
    fulltime_spt[t] += "m"
```

**Output:**

```
['5:00pm', '12:00am', '9:16']
```

Answer (score 2):

`pm` and `am` both have an `m` at the end, so you could split on that and add it back afterwards if you know the format of the time strings will always be the same.

```
[e if len(e) < 5 else e+'m' for e in '7:57am5:13pm9:16'.split('m')]
>>['7:57am', '5:13pm', '9:16']
```

If you really want to use a RegEx to find the times, you can also use the following RegEx:

```
re.findall('[\d:]+(?:am|pm|$)', '7:57am5:13pm9:16')
>>['7:57am', '5:13pm', '9:16']
```

Explanation: The function will find all of the strings that match the RegEx.

`[\d:]+` : A digit or a colon once or more times

`(?:am|pm|$)` : A non-capturing group specifying `am`, `pm`, or the end of the string.

Thus, the RegEx will find all groups of digits or colons followed by `am` or `pm` or the end of the string.

Comment: I hadn't considered splitting on the `m` - I'll have a play with this and see how it works for me

Answer (score 2):

I used the re module to do this, let me know if it's what you need

```
import re

date = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+/\d+/\d\d", x)[0]       # Search for a group of upper or lower case letters, followed by / followed by 2 numbers followed by / followed by 2 numbers and return the first of these patterns found
start, stop = re.findall("\d+:\d+[ap]m", x[len(date):]) # search the string from the end of the date for a number (any amount of digits) followed by : followed by another number (of any amount of digits) and the string am or pm, and assign the first to start and second to stop
```

Here are some examples of it. First, I'll wrap it in a function for the exercise. Lets call it `f`

```
import re

f(x):
    date = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+/\d+/\d\d", x)[0]
    start, stop = re.findall("\d+:\d+[a|p]m", x[len(date):])
    print(date, start, stop)

>>> f("Jun/22/177:57am5:13pm9:16")
Jun/22/17 7:57am 5:13pm
>>> f("May/13/1712:00am1:03pm")
May/13/17 12:00am 1:03pm
>>> f("Dec/1/1712:00am1:03pm")
Dec/1/17 12:00am 1:03pm
```

*I have made a small change in the way of getting the date, please make note of that. This way it handles months of 1 digit.

Comment: What are `x` and `y`?  I have `x` in my code above but no `y`. Are you reusing my `x`?  Where does the `y` come from?

Comment: You mention in the comment "search... for a 1 number followed by : ", however what if the number is `10`, `11`, `12`?

Comment: give me 5 minutes to be more clear in the answer, and `y` was supposed to be `date`, my bad

Comment: OK, I made it more clear/fixed a small error. I'll add some examples too

Comment: `[a|p]` will also match `|`. You want just `[ap]`

Answer (score 2):

One convenient way is to use a regular expression. If you have not heard of these before, you can read up on them in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html). Basically, they allow you to search for patterns in a string rather than specific characters. Here is an example that would work for the string you mentioned.

```
# Import standard regular expression module
import re

# Find all substrings that match a specific pattern
x = "Jun/22/177:57am5:13pm9:16"             # Our string
pattern = '[1-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9][ap]m'     # Explained below
re.findall(pattern, x)                      # Find all occurrences of pattern
```

Result:

```
['7:57am', '5:13pm']
```

This pattern, for example, could find the duration

```
pattern2 = '[0-9]+:[0-9][0-9]$'
re.findall(pattern2, x)
```

Result:

```
['9:16']
```

Let's quickly look at our first pattern for those new to regular expressions:

```
pattern = '[1-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9][ap]m'
```

The `[]` mean "any of these characters match", and `?` means "the last character may or may not be present". So this looks for a 1 or 2 (but we're okay if there is not a 1 or 2 because of the `?`), followed by any number from 0 to 9, followed by ":", followed by a number from 0 to 5, followed by a number from 0 to 9, followed by either an "a" or "p" (`[ap]`), followed by "m".

The second pattern has a `+`, which just means "one or more of", and a `$`, which means "this is the end of the string". That should help you get started.

An alternative, if you would rather not use regular expressions, the `.isdigit` command might come in handy:

```
>>> '1'.isdigit()
True
>>> 'a'.isdigit()
False
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you.  I always steer clear of regex because I don't understand it, but you have talked through it well.  I'll have a play with this as well.

Answer (score -2):

The below will do

```
x = "Jun/22/177:57am5:13pm9:16"

t = x.replace(fulldate_str, "").replace('am',' ').replace('pm',' ').split()
print(t)

['7:57', '5:13', '9:16']
```

basically you first take off the full date (that you already split) and then you string replace in correspondence of `am` and `pm`.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, I am going to lose the `am`/`pm`?  Unfortunately that is needed, otherwise a start of `5:30` and a stop of `7:30` may be 2 hours or 14 hours of operation.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, I assumed you only need the digits.